# Écrit-on « ou autre » ou bien « ou autres » ?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe, pluriel, locutions

Par exemple :

> Je vais apprendre du vocabulaire, des textes, ou autre(s?)

Quelle est la bonne orthographe ? Les deux formes fournissent un nombre conséquent de résultats dans une recherche web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il y a plusieurs manières d'analyser grammaticalement le mot *autre(s)*.

Il peut avoir la même valeur que les autres branches de la disjonction, ce qui conduit à l'accorder avec ces autres branches.

> Je vais apprendre du vocabulaire, des textes, ou autre(s).
>   Je vais apprendre du vocabulaire, de la grammaire, ou autre.
>   Je vais apprendre des textes, des mots ou autres.

On peut considérer que *autre* est un adjectif qui qualifie un nom omis tel que *possibilité*, *éventualité*, etc. Dans ce cas, il est sémantiquement valable de mettre ce nom au singulier ou au pluriel. Suivant cette interprétation, l'utilisation du singulier suggère une disjonction exclusive, dans laquelle une seule autre possibilité peut être retenue :

> Pendant mon voyage, je vais apprendre du vocabulaire (dans mon dictionnaire), des textes (dans mon recueil), ou autre (peut-être de la grammaire dans mon manuel). Je n'ai de place dans mes bagages que pour un seul livre.
>   Il est en vacacances sur une île tropicale, Réunion, Guadeloupe ou autre.

Tandis que le pluriel suggère une disjonction inclusive, puisqu'il exprime la possibilité de retenir plusieurs éventualités :

> Ce soir, je vais apprendre du vocabulaire, des textes, ou autres. En fait, je ne suis pas fatigué, je crois que je vais apprendre toutes mes leçons.
>   Tous les ans, il part en vacances sur une île tropicale, Réunion, Guadeloupe ou autres.

On peut aussi analyser l'ellipse comme partant d'une expression figée telle que *autre chose*, qui force le singulier.

On peut encore analyser *autre* comme représentant la collection de toutes les éventualités non mentionnées explicitement. Dans ce cas, *autre* s'accordant comme une disjonction, les deux nombres sont possibles (du moment que chaque éventualité peut être vue comme un singulier) : [l'un et l'autre se dit ou se disent](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominique_Bouhours#cite_note-0).

Bref, la grammaire n'impose pas le singulier ou le pluriel. À titre personnel, aucun des deux ne me choque.

<sub>Je ne sais pas comment mesurer les fréquences d'usage. L'expression « ou autre(s) » peut se retrouver dans de très nombreux contextes où un accord s'impose, à commencer par les cas où *autre* est suivi d'un nom.</sub>

Comment: autres is a pronoun here.